# qooxdoo json/request transport method

Tags: json, qooxdoo

I try to send a request to my server via GET, but qooxdoo sends request as OPTIONS. Is any way to change this behaviour?

I try to use qx.data.store.Json (url) and qx.io.remote.Request (url, "GET", type) but result is same in both cases.

My version of qooxdoo is 1.0.1, browsers are FF 3.5.6 and Chromium 5.0.361.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely a problem due to cross browser restrictions. Give the JSONP store a try and deliver your data as JSONP to get rid of that problem.

Comment: Thanks! JSONP works. I read http://news.qooxdoo.org/tutorial-part-3-time-for-communication - but I completely don't understand how to use JSONP store.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because I try to send cross-domain request from file:/// to http://.
If I deploy a test application to server - it works fine.